# How to make max(date) in the where clause condition

Tags: mysql

I am using this query to query out data only from the latest date

```
SELECT total_personnel 
FROM fcponc
WHERE day_date=
   SELECT MAX(day_date) FROM fcponc;
```

but there is an error -- please advise how to correct it

```
SELECT total_personnel 
FROM fcponc 
WHERE day_date=
   SELECT MAX(day_date) FROM fcponc;
```

Comment: what is the column type of `day_date` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need have brackets surrounding your inner query

```
SELECT total_personnel 
FROM fcponc 
WHERE day_date = 
    (SELECT MAX(day_date) FROM fcponc);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your sub-query in parenthesis:

```
SELECT total_personnel 
FROM fact_personnel_on_site_category 
WHERE day_date= ( SELECT MAX(day_date) FROM fact_personnel_on_site_category);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT total_personnel 
FROM fact_personnel_on_site_category 
WHERE day_date=
   (SELECT MAX(day_date) FROM fact_personnel_on_site_category);
```

Please make your inner query in brackets ... is it working for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use (__) brackets to make second query separate.

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE date_column = (
SELECT MAX( date_column )
FROM table_name
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will be faster:

```
SELECT total_personnel  
FROM fact_personnel_on_site_category  
order by day_date desc  
limit 1;
```